# 3rd order Runge-Kutta (RK3) method in Python for matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I'm struggling to try and put my idea of what I have for this problem into Python, I'm stuck on trying to put the bvector(x) function to give me my required output.

---

> [image: Q1]

---

> [image: Q2]

---

> [image: Q3]

Comment: Your pictures 2 and 3 are the same picture.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: This same task was [asked about once before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532838/115115), only in matlab instead of python. Compare and enhance your question with your actual questions about the task.

Comment: As an example, you could have `bvector = lambda x: np.array([x+1,x**2]);` as forcing term / right side / inhomogeneity.

Comment: As of right now, I'm struggling to even be able to start the problem as I'm not really sure what I'm being asked to find, even when reading the problem again. 1. What am I trying to find? 2. What is x_j referring to? 3. Is there an example problem that has been done before this?

Comment: I've also updated the pictures. Thanks for pointing this out Arthur.

Comment: Moreover, the introduction of the matrix A I find slightly confusing

Comment: Why don't you try and compute the solution to the standard problem $y' = \lambda y, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ first, then modify your code to include matrices afterward.

Comment: It might help if people knew more about how you came to be working on this problem. If this is an exercise in a book on numerical analysis, where Runge-Kutta methods have already been discussed extensively and you are merely now asked to try one in software, you might get one kind of answer; if this is from a course on Python programming that has said nothing at all about Runge-Kutta methods up to this point, and you have never seen such a thing in your other studies, then you might get a very different kind of answer.

Comment: It's the latter, this is the first time Runge-Kutta has been discussed on this course.

Comment: You might edit that fact into the question text above, preferably at the very start where it will be most likely to be noticed by anyone who sees this question.

Comment: What exactly is the python topic? Numerical methods? Or array management with numpy? // In [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395882/115115) I implemented the vector RK4 method in python, with a slightly different interface but similar overall functionality. There exist many other implementations in the net, ones for systems are more rare.

Comment: The Python topic is numerical methods, and I've looked at many RK4 methods online in Python but the distinct thing throwing me off this problem is the fact there's a matrix A and vector b where every other problem just deals with scalar entries

Comment: Yes, that's why you need a vector-oriented implementation. You can transform your input into the standard ODE format with `def f(x,y): return A.dot(y)+bvector(x);`, where `A` is a 2d numpy array, `y` an 1d numpy array and `bvector` returns numpy arrays or scalars.

Answer (score 0):

#### bvector

This encodes the inhomogeneity in the linear system of differential equations 
$$
y'(x)=A\,y(x)+b(x)
$$
Thus $b(x)$ is a vector of the same dimension as $y$. As the vector addition in matlab and python has a mode of adding a scalar, adding it to all components, one can simplify the current case of a zero vector to just returning the scalar $0$.

```
bvector = lambda x: 0
```

If this vector is non-trivial, you would have to return a proper vector, for instance using `numpy.array` as vector type. In dimension two this could look like

```
bvector = lambda x: np.array([x+1,x**2]);
```

#### RK3 step

If the current state is `xn,yn` then the step of size `h` is implemented as just repeating the (corrected) formulas,

```
rk3step(xn,yn,h):
    y1 = yn+h*(A.dot(yn)+bvector(xn));
    y2 = 0.75*yn+0.25*y1+0.25*h*(A.dot(y1)+bvector(xn+h));
    return (yn+2*y2+2*h*(A.dot(y2)+bvector(xn+0.5*h)))/3;
```

#### A possible loop

This you now can embed into a list construction loop

```
def rk3(A, bvector, y0, interval, N):
    def rk3step: ...
    x = np.linspace(*interval,N+1);
    y = [y0]
    for n in range(N):
        y.append(rk3step(x[n],y[n],x[n+1]-x[n]));
    return x,np.asarray(y).T
```